# CollectionObject.ToList().AddRange() is working

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have been searching for why collectionObj.ToList().AddRange() is not working but haven't found any use resources so far.
I have a ICollection object = new List() object defined. But when I try to add few more items to that List object using AddRange. It is not adding the items to it.

Below is the scenario where AddRange is not working

```
ICollection<Standard> firstList = new List<Standard>(){ new Standard() { StandardID = 1 },
                                                                       new Standard() { StandardID = 2 },
                                                                       new Standard() { StandardID = 3 }};

Console.WriteLine(firstList.GetType()); // Shows the type as List

ICollection<Standard> secondList = new List<Standard>(){new Standard() { StandardID = 1 },
                                                                      new Standard() { StandardID = 2 },
                                                                      new Standard() { StandardID = 3 } };

// Convert to List and used AddRange(). But new items are getting added
firstList.ToList().AddRange(secondList);
```

But if I do object.ToList() and assign it to a temporary variable and then add items to that temporary variable, then I am able to add items to it.
Below is the code.

```
var tempList = firstList.ToList();
// System now adds the secondList items to tempList
tempList.AddRange(secondList);
```

Could you please help me.

Comment: Isnt `firstList` already a `List<Standard>`?  So why do `ToList()` on it at all?

Comment: ICollection doesn't contain an AddRange(), so I had to do ToList() on firstList and then do an AddRange.

Comment: Does this count in XY problem ?

Comment: Any reason why you need to use `ICollection`? Why not just `List`?

Answer (score 3):

`ToList()` returns a List - and you throw it away.

`firstList.ToList().AddRange(secondList);`

`firstList.ToList()` is a new List with no name (you don't assign it to a variable)

You add secondList to that unnamed list. `firstList` is unchanged.